# Call plugin function multiple times on document ready?

Tags: jquery, function, document-ready

I'w made jquery plugin that style desired elements to stylish windows.

I need to call plug function on document ready so desired elements can be stylized and hidden, waiting for trigger to show them.

The problem is when I call functions for first time ondocument.ready to style elements, it won't run more than once, meaning that I can only style and hide one element on document.ready. I still can do it manually by trigger it twice with some other event.

I think there is a problem in plugin script that won't allow triggering the function more than once at same time!

Here is the code, firs call will use the plugin second won't on document ready. Any help would be appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    $("#addAdmin").flexWin();
    $("#msg").flexWin();

});
```

and plugin script:

```
    (function($){$.fn.extend({ 
    flexWin: function(options) {
        $(window).resize(function() {
            resizer()
        });

        var defaults = {
            background:'#000',
            width: '400px',
            height:'400px',
            defTab: 0,
            closeX: "block", 
            show: 0,
            zindex: 0,
        };

        if (options==null) {                

        }

        var settings = $.extend(defaults, options);

        var n = $("#menu > li").size();         
        var o =settings;
        var objID = $(this).attr('id');
        var obj = $('#'+objID);
        var finalWidth 
        var finalHeight         
        //CSS Adjustments
        if (o.width.indexOf("%") >= 0){
            finalWidth = $(window).width() * (parseFloat(o.width)/100)+"px"
        }
        else{
            finalWidth = o.width
        }               
        if (o.height.indexOf("%") >= 0){
            finalHeight = $(window).width() * (parseFloat(o.width)/100)+"px"
        }
        else{
            finalHeight = o.height
        }

        if (!$('#header',obj).length) {

            obj.css({'width':finalWidth,'height':finalHeight,'overflow': 'hidden', 'border':'solid 2px #0173ff',
            'border-radius': '20px', '-webkit-border-radius': '20px', '-moz-border-radius': '20px'});

            //center window
            obj.css("position","absolute");
            obj.css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - obj.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
            obj.css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - obj.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px"); 

            //Transparent background
            copystyle ={
                'background':'#ffffff',
                'opacity':'0.7',
                '-moz-opacity':'0.7',
                'filter':'alpha(opacity=70)',
                'position':'absolute',
                'z-index':'-1',
                'height':'100%',
                'width':'100%',
                'border-radius':'20px', 
                '-webkit-border-radius': '20px', 
                '-moz-border-radius': '20px',
            };
            obj.append('<div id="'+objID+'TransBG"></div><div id="header"></div><div id="close">&#10005</div>');    

            //$('<div id="'+objID+'TransBG"></div>').insertBefore(obj);
            $('#'+objID+'TransBG').css(copystyle);

            //objWB = $('#'+objID+'TransBG') //id of main element With Backgroud                    

            obj.hide();     
            //Transparent background____________

            //Shape objects


            if(n==0){
                var title = obj.attr("title");
                $('#header',obj).append('<div id="title"></div>');
                $('#title',obj).css({'font-size':'20px','color':'#0173ff','text-align':'center','line-height':'30px','width':'100%','height':'34px'});  
                $('#title',obj).text(title);
            }


            $('#header',obj).css({
                'position':'absolute', 'top':'0px','left':'0px','margin':'0px','padding':'0px', 'z-index':-1,
                'width':'100%','height':'35px',
                'border-radius': '15px 15px 0 0',
                '-webkit-border-radius': '15px 15px 0 0',
                '-moz-border-radius':'15px 15px 0 0',

                'background': '#ffffff',
                'background':'-moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #f1f1f1 60%, #e1e1e1 84%, #f6f6f6 94%, #0173ff 100%)', 
                'background': '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(60%,#f1f1f1), color-stop(84%,#e1e1e1), color-stop(94%,#f6f6f6),color-stop(100%,#0173ff))',
                'background': '-o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 60%,#e1e1e1 84%,#f6f6f6 94%, #0173ff 100%)',                 
                'background': '-ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 60%,#e1e1e1 84%,#f6f6f6 94%, #0173ff 100%)',
                'background': 'linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 60%,#e1e1e1 84%,#f6f6f6 94%, #0173ff 100%)',
                'background-image': '-webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 60%,#e1e1e1 84%,#f6f6f6 94%, #0173ff 100%)',              
                'filter': 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr="#ffffff", endColorstr="#f6f6f6",GradientType=0 )',                            
            });
            $('#close',obj).click(function(){obj.flexWin()}).css({
                'position':'absolute', 'top':'6px','right':'6px','margin':'0px','padding':'0px',
                'width':'20px','height':'20px','color': '#0173ff','text-align':'center','line-height':'20px','font-size': '14px',   
                'cursor': 'hand','cursor': 'pointer', 'display': o.closeX,              
            });
            if ( o.show==1) {
                obj.show();                 
            }
            else{
                obj.hide();
            }
            if ( $.browser.msie ) {
                $('#header',obj).css({'border-bottom':'solid 2px #1E55B0'});
            }

            //$(obj).delay(300).slideToggle("fast");
        }
        else if ($('#header',obj).length&&options==null) {
             obj.slideToggle("fast");   
        } 
        else if (($('#header',obj).length&&options!=null&&obj.css('display')=='none')) {
             obj.slideToggle("fast");   
             resizer();
        }
        else if ($('#header',obj).length&&options!=null&&obj.css('display')!='none') {
             resizer();
        } 
        //______________________

        if (obj.length > 0) {

        }

        //window style to class objects
        $('.styleIT',obj).css({
                'border-radius': '15px 15px 0 0',
                '-webkit-border-radius': '15px 15px 0 0',
                '-moz-border-radius':'15px 15px 0 0',

                'background': '#ffffff',
                'background':'-moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #f1f1f1 60%, #e1e1e1 84%, #f6f6f6 94%, #0173ff 100%)', 
                'background': '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(60%,#f1f1f1), color-stop(84%,#e1e1e1), color-stop(94%,#f6f6f6),color-stop(100%,#0173ff))',
                'background': '-o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 60%,#e1e1e1 84%,#f6f6f6 94%, #0173ff 100%)',                 
                'background': '-ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 60%,#e1e1e1 84%,#f6f6f6 94%, #0173ff 100%)',
                'background': 'linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 60%,#e1e1e1 84%,#f6f6f6 94%, #0173ff 100%)',
                'background-image': '-webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 60%,#e1e1e1 84%,#f6f6f6 94%, #0173ff 100%)',              
                'filter': 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr="#ffffff", endColorstr="#f6f6f6",GradientType=0 )',                            
        });

        //Control window size and position on browser window resize
        function resizer() {
            if (o.width.indexOf("%") >= 0){
                finalWidth = $(window).width() * (parseFloat(o.width)/100)+"px"
            }
            else{
                finalWidth = o.width                    
            }
            if (o.height.indexOf("%") >= 0){
                finalHeight = $(window).height() * (parseFloat(o.height)/100)+"px"
            }
            else{
                finalHeight = o.height
            }   
            obj.stop().animate({
                'left':Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - parseFloat(finalWidth)) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft()) +'px',
                'top':Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - parseFloat(finalHeight)) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop()) +'px',
                'width':finalWidth,
                'height':finalHeight,
            }, "fast");
            objWB.stop().animate({
                'left':Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - parseFloat(finalWidth)) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft()) +'px',
                'top':Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - parseFloat(finalHeight)) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop()) +'px',
                'width':finalWidth,
                'height':finalHeight,
            }, "fast");
            tabSpace = parseFloat(finalWidth)-35;
            tabWidth = tabSpace/tabCount
            $("li>h1", obj).css({'width':tabWidth+'px'});
            $("span").text(tabWidth); 
            return false;
        };                  


        var tabSpace = parseFloat(finalWidth)-35;
        var tabCount = $("li", obj).length;
        var tabWidth = tabSpace/tabCount



        return this.each(function() {

            var items = $("li>h1", obj);  
            $("li>h1", obj).css({
                'font-size':'11px', 'z-index':10, 'color':'#2D2D2D','margin':'0px','padding':'0px','text-align':'center','line-height':'30px','overflow':'hidden',
                'width':tabWidth+'px','height':'34px','float':'left',
                'border-radius': '15px 15px 0 0','border-right':'solid 1px #2D2D2D',
                '-webkit-border-radius': '15px 15px 0 0',
                '-moz-border-radius':'15px 15px 0 0',


                'background': '#232020',
                'background':'-moz-linear-gradient(top,  #232020 0%, #000000 68%, #262626 94%, #333333 100%)',  
                'background': '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#232020), color-stop(68%,#000000), color-stop(94%,#262626), color-stop(100%,#333333))',
                'background': '-o-linear-gradient(top,  #232020 0%,#000000 68%,#262626 94%,#333333 100%)',                  
                'background': '-ms-linear-gradient(top,  #232020 0%,#000000 68%,#262626 94%,#333333 100%)',
                'background': 'linear-gradient(to bottom,  #232020 0%,#000000 68%,#262626 94%,#333333 100%)',
                'background-image': '-webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #232020 0%,#000000 68%,#262626 94%,#333333 100%)',               
                'filter': 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr="#45484d", endColorstr="#000000",GradientType=0 )',    
            });  
            //$("li:not(:eq(2))>h1",this).css("color","red");  
            items.mouseover(function() {
                //$("span").text($(this).parent().index());
                if($(this).parent().index()!=o.defTab){
                    $(this).css({
                        'color':'#fff','border-right':'solid 1px #fff','border-bottom':'solid 1px #fff',
                    })
                }                   
            }).mouseout(function() {
                $("span").text("0"); 
                if($(this).parent().index()!=o.defTab){ 
                    $(this).css({
                        'color':'#2D2D2D','border-right':'solid 1px #2D2D2D','border-bottom':'none',
                    }) 
                }
            }).click(function() {
                o.defTab = $(this).parent().index()
                $("li:eq("+o.defTab+")>h1",obj).css({
                    'color':'#0173ff','border-right':'solid 1px #0173ff','border-left':'solid 1px #0173ff','border-bottom':'none',
                    'background': '#232020',
                    'background':'-moz-linear-gradient(top,  #232020 0%, #000000 68%, #262626 94%, #0173ff 100%)',  
                    'background': '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#232020), color-stop(68%,#000000), color-stop(94%,#262626), color-stop(100%,#0173ff))',
                    'background': '-o-linear-gradient(top,  #232020 0%,#000000 68%,#262626 94%,#0173ff 100%)',                  
                    'background': '-ms-linear-gradient(top,  #232020 0%,#000000 68%,#262626 94%,#0173ff 100%)',
                    'background': 'linear-gradient(to bottom,  #232020 0%,#000000 68%,#262626 94%,#0173ff 100%)',
                    'background-image': '-webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #232020 0%,#000000 68%,#262626 94%,#0173ff 100%)',               
                    'filter': 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr="#45484d", endColorstr="#000000",GradientType=0 )',
                });
                $("li:not(:eq("+o.defTab+"))>h1",obj).css({
                    'color':'#2D2D2D','border-right':'solid 1px #2D2D2D','border-left':'solid 1px #2D2D2D',
                    'background': '#232020',
                    'background':'-moz-linear-gradient(top,  #232020 0%, #000000 68%, #262626 94%, #333333 100%)',  
                    'background': '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#232020), color-stop(68%,#000000), color-stop(94%,#262626), color-stop(100%,#333333))',
                    'background': '-o-linear-gradient(top,  #232020 0%,#000000 68%,#262626 94%,#333333 100%)',                  
                    'background': '-ms-linear-gradient(top,  #232020 0%,#000000 68%,#262626 94%,#333333 100%)',
                    'background': 'linear-gradient(to bottom,  #232020 0%,#000000 68%,#262626 94%,#333333 100%)',
                    'background-image': '-webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #232020 0%,#000000 68%,#262626 94%,#333333 100%)',               
                    'filter': 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr="#45484d", endColorstr="#000000",GradientType=0 )',    
                });                      
            });
            $("li:eq("+o.defTab+")>h1",obj).css({
                'color':'#0173ff','border-right':'solid 1px #0173ff','border-left':'solid 1px #0173ff',
                'background': '#232020',
                'background':'-moz-linear-gradient(top,  #232020 0%, #000000 68%, #262626 94%, #0173ff 100%)',  
                'background': '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#232020), color-stop(68%,#000000), color-stop(94%,#262626), color-stop(100%,#0173ff))',
                'background': '-o-linear-gradient(top,  #232020 0%,#000000 68%,#262626 94%,#0173ff 100%)',                  
                'background': '-ms-linear-gradient(top,  #232020 0%,#000000 68%,#262626 94%,#0173ff 100%)',
                'background': 'linear-gradient(to bottom,  #232020 0%,#000000 68%,#262626 94%,#0173ff 100%)',
                'background-image': '-webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #232020 0%,#000000 68%,#262626 94%,#0173ff 100%)',               
                'filter': 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr="#45484d", endColorstr="#000000",GradientType=0 )',
            });  
        });
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: `var n = $("#menu > li").size()` inside the plugin creates a dependency on structure of the page's markup. This is going to affect the plugin's _plugin behavior_  IMO.

Comment: I found that this code was creating that problem:

if ( $.browser.msie ) {
                $('#header',obj).css({'border-bottom':'solid 2px #1E55B0'});
            }

Comment: you're welcome. Please also do visit the page and tryout the boilerplate I've mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a lot of code there but I think you're missing a key point here. Your plugin doesn't have to ability of being applied on multiple elements, like

```
$("#addAdmin,#msg").flexWin();
```

This is probably because you're not following the right jQuery plugin pattern for this sort of plugin. You need to have a class/function inside your plugin that does all the heavy work of your plugin and can be invoked on your parameter elements inside the plugin as follows

```
/* ... some plugin code .. */
this.each(function(){ /*the heavy work here */})
/* ... some plugin code .. */
```

where `this` is the list of elements the plugin is being applied on, `"#addAdmin,#msg"` in this case. I've found that [this jquery plugin boilerplate](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/jquery-plugin-template/) is helpful in your situation.

I hope it helps.

### Update

*adding helpful comment to the answer body*
`var n = $("#menu > li").size()` inside the plugin creates a dependency on structure of the page's markup. This is going to affect the plugin's *plugin behavior* IMO

Comment: Thank you for advice, I'm relatively new to this that's why I'm going hard way here. Thank you for link , next time I'll use that as a base to create a new plugin.
As for your Updated reply I see what's you point and I change it, but anyway that wasn't used currently in plugin so that was harmless!